# Rendering Large JSON dataset causes browser to hang/crash/irresponsive

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter-3, infinite-scroll

I am fetching a large json data-set containing 1500+ records with information about hotels and trying to render that into HTML which is causing the browser to hang/crash or become totally irresponsive.

The application is a CodeIgniter 3 (PHP/MySQL) application where one of the controller methods send a curl request to a remote server and receives a huge data-set that I need to render.

I am rendering it all on server side and then echoing the view as ajax response which is clearly not working.

Another problem is that I cannot get the data from server in chunks, either I will get it all at once or nothing at all.

At this point, I am out of ideas, is there are better way to render the data-set than processing whole data-set on server side and echoing it back to browser (obviously the response size is so large that it is causing lag).

I am open to any feasible suggestions/ solutions that may work in this scenario.

What I am looking for is to render a chunk of received data-set once and as I scroll the page, it load more data from the remaining data-set.

My goal is to have a quickly rendered page/DOM where I can do some DOM manipulation such as sorting, filtering etc. without causing the whole browser to crash.

Any help would be highly appreciated and I am open to trying new things.

Regards,

Shyam S.

Comment: you sending cURL request at the server, can't you do the same request using javascript from the browser?

Comment: No, request requires confidential authentication information that I can't expose.

Answer (score 0):

Initial thoughts are to retrieve in batches, enough to be useful and not degrade experience of the user too much. However, you say it's all or nothing. In that case, it seems you need some kind of intermediate store. Maybe you write the JSON to a json file locally and then perform AJAX in batches on your local file. A file is just one example, you could potentially put it in memory, but the same problem may occur. You could stick it in a DB too.

Regardless of what you do, loading lots of HTML will cause the browser to perform slowly. You'd be better of loading 100 (or whatever amount is reasonable) and as the user scrolls down trigger the next set of records to load.